# Gae Server error received in app api response

Tags: ios, objective-c, google-app-engine, google-cloud-datastore, gae-eclipse-plugin

In my app we have used GAE for backhand support. We have received following text in response some times.

```
"<html><head>
<meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html;charset=utf-8">
<title>500 Server Error</title>
</head>
<body text=#000000 bgcolor=#ffffff>
<h1>Error: Server Error</h1>
<h2>The server encountered an error and could not complete your request.<p>Please try again in 30 seconds.</h2>
<h2></h2>
</body></html>"
```

- We have used Java 7.
- GAE RAM 512 MB taken.
- How can we stop receiving that type of HTML Code from server?

  - In Console we have show this type of waring.

  "A problem was encountered with the process that handled this request, causing it to exit. This is likely to cause a new process to be used for the next request to your application. If you see this message frequently, you may be throwing exceptions during the initialization of your application. (Error code 104)"

  Can this warning cause 500 server error ?

Comment: it means that you have an error on server side. you have to fix this, i guess

Comment: We get hardline exception error due to time out some times so how can we solve that issue because that cause app crash. @IgorArtamonov

Comment: so the real question is "_how to handle deadline exception_"? take a look at https://cloud.google.com/appengine/articles/deadlineexceedederrors

Comment: yes we have checked this page and added code like below 
"catch(DeadlineExceededException ex){
    jsonData.put("statusCode", "2");
    jsonData.put("message", "");
    jsonData.put("isException", "1");
   }"
but not working.When we check again it will give same html text in response..

Comment: did you check it on production server? or local dev only?

Comment: we have checked in both server @IgorArtamonov

Comment: ok, I guess you have to start a new question here, with code you've used to catch exception, how you produce result, etc

Comment: Hi , In console  we have checked and find out below text "A problem was encountered with the process that handled this request, causing it to exit. This is likely to cause a new process to be used for the next request to your application. If you see this message frequently, you may be throwing exceptions during the initialization of your application. (Error code 104)" @IgorArtamonov

Comment: most likely it takes too long to start your app, make sure it starts in less than 30 seconds